# Postrgresql GIN index but slow query

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.8. 303605 rows. Created index `npdb_swedish_custom_index`

```
create index npdb_swedish_custom_index on products
                    using GIN(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', name||price||description||brand))
```

But 6.3s it's not great perfocmance, but `Bitmap Index Scan on npdb_swedish_custom_index` present in analyse,  how to optimization this query ?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
            SELECT
                products_alias.id,
                products_alias.sku,
                products_alias.name AS "name",
                products_alias.description,
                products_alias.category,
                products_alias.price,
                products_alias.shipping,
                products_alias.currency,
                products_alias.instock,
                products_alias.product_url AS "productUrl",
                products_alias.image_url AS "imageUrl",
                products_alias.tracking_url AS "trackingUrl",
                products_alias.brand,
                products_alias.shop,
                products_alias.original_price AS "originalPrice",
                products_alias.ean,
                products_alias.manufacturer_article_number AS "manufacturerArticleNumber",
                products_alias.extras,
                products_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
                products_alias.brand_relation_id AS "brandRelationId",
                products_alias.shop_relation_id AS "shopRelationId",
                ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description||products_alias.brand), to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Barn&Xylitol&Cool&tshirt&Speeder|Tränings&Tshirts|Träningskläder|subSkjortor|Skjortor|Långärmade&tshirts|subTshirts|Tshirts|Barn')) AS rank
            FROM products products_alias

            WHERE to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description||products_alias.brand) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Barn&Xylitol&Cool&tshirt&Speeder|Tränings&Tshirts|Träningskläder|subSkjortor|Skjortor|Långärmade&tshirts|subTshirts|Tshirts|Barn')
            AND products_alias.id != 304486
            ORDER BY rank DESC
            LIMIT 4
            OFFSET 0

Limit  (cost=50714.06..50714.54 rows=4 width=931) (actual time=6310.489..6310.493 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=50714.06..56982.41 rows=52352 width=931) (actual time=6310.488..6312.928 rows=4 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Sort  (cost=49714.00..49746.72 rows=13088 width=931) (actual time=6305.031..6305.032 rows=4 loops=5)
              Sort Key: (ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('swedish'::regconfig, ((((name)::text || (price)::text) || description) || (brand)::text)), '''barn'' & ''xylitol'' & ''cool'' & ''tshirt'' & ''speed'' | ''träning'' & ''tshirt'' | ''träningskläd'' | ''subskjort'' | ''skjort'' | ''långärm'' & ''tshirt'' | ''subtshirt'' | ''tshirt'' | ''barn'''::tsquery)) DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 31kB
              Worker 2:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
              Worker 3:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on products products_alias  (cost=2053.73..49517.68 rows=13088 width=931) (actual time=39.352..6283.279 rows=9727 loops=5)
                    Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('swedish'::regconfig, ((((name)::text || (price)::text) || description) || (brand)::text)) @@ '''barn'' & ''xylitol'' & ''cool'' & ''tshirt'' & ''speed'' | ''träning'' & ''tshirt'' | ''träningskläd'' | ''subskjort'' | ''skjort'' | ''långärm'' & ''tshirt'' | ''subtshirt'' | ''tshirt'' | ''barn'''::tsquery)
                    Filter: (id <> 304486)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=5298
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on npdb_swedish_custom_index  (cost=0.00..2040.64 rows=52352 width=0) (actual time=38.177..38.177 rows=48935 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (to_tsvector('swedish'::regconfig, ((((name)::text || (price)::text) || description) || (brand)::text)) @@ '''barn'' & ''xylitol'' & ''cool'' & ''tshirt'' & ''speed'' | ''träning'' & ''tshirt'' | ''träningskläd'' | ''subskjort'' | ''skjort'' | ''långärm'' & ''tshirt'' | ''subtshirt'' | ''tshirt'' | ''barn'''::tsquery)
Planning Time: 0.301 ms
Execution Time: 6312.993 ms
```

Anither case I created indexes for `created_at`

```
    'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS created_desc_index ON products (created_at DESC NULLS LAST)'
    'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS created_asc_index ON products (created_at ASC NULLS LAST)'
    'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS price_desc_index ON products (price DESC NULLS LAST)'
    'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS price_asc_index ON products (price ASC NULLS LAST)'
```

but still query slowly and I did not found description about sort index in analyze, it information should be present ?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
            SELECT
                products_alias.id,
                products_alias.sku,
                products_alias.name AS "name",
                products_alias.description,
                products_alias.category,
                products_alias.price,
                products_alias.shipping,
                products_alias.currency,
                products_alias.instock,
                products_alias.product_url AS "productUrl",
                products_alias.image_url AS "imageUrl",
                products_alias.tracking_url AS "trackingUrl",
                products_alias.brand,
                products_alias.shop,
                products_alias.original_price AS "originalPrice",
                products_alias.ean,
                products_alias.manufacturer_article_number AS "manufacturerArticleNumber",
                products_alias.extras,
                products_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
                products_alias.brand_relation_id AS "brandRelationId",
                products_alias.shop_relation_id AS "shopRelationId",
                ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description||products_alias.brand), to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Barn&Xylitol&Cool&tshirt&Speeder|Tränings&Tshirts|Träningskläder|subSkjortor|Skjortor|Långärmade&tshirts|subTshirts|Tshirts|Barn')) AS rank
            FROM products products_alias

            WHERE to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description||products_alias.brand) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Barn&Xylitol&Cool&tshirt&Speeder|Tränings&Tshirts|Träningskläder|subSkjortor|Skjortor|Långärmade&tshirts|subTshirts|Tshirts|Barn')

            ORDER BY products_alias.created_at DESC NULLS LAST

Gather Merge  (cost=51379.97..57648.32 rows=52352 width=931) (actual time=6582.388..6611.045 rows=48636 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 4
  Workers Launched: 4
  ->  Sort  (cost=50379.92..50412.64 rows=13088 width=931) (actual time=6570.277..6571.587 rows=9727 loops=5)
        Sort Key: created_at DESC NULLS LAST
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 17187kB
        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 16964kB
        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 16458kB
        Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 16281kB
        Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 17238kB
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on products products_alias  (cost=2053.73..49484.96 rows=13088 width=931) (actual time=85.944..6539.764 rows=9727 loops=5)
              Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('swedish'::regconfig, ((((name)::text || (price)::text) || description) || (brand)::text)) @@ '''barn'' & ''xylitol'' & ''cool'' & ''tshirt'' & ''speed'' | ''träning'' & ''tshirt'' | ''träningskläd'' | ''subskjort'' | ''skjort'' | ''långärm'' & ''tshirt'' | ''subtshirt'' | ''tshirt'' | ''barn'''::tsquery)
              Heap Blocks: exact=4981
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on npdb_swedish_custom_index  (cost=0.00..2040.64 rows=52352 width=0) (actual time=89.060..89.060 rows=48935 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (to_tsvector('swedish'::regconfig, ((((name)::text || (price)::text) || description) || (brand)::text)) @@ '''barn'' & ''xylitol'' & ''cool'' & ''tshirt'' & ''speed'' | ''träning'' & ''tshirt'' | ''träningskläd'' | ''subskjort'' | ''skjort'' | ''långärm'' & ''tshirt'' | ''subtshirt'' | ''tshirt'' | ''barn'''::tsquery)
Planning Time: 0.684 ms
Execution Time: 6614.191 ms
```

Comment: The slow step could be reading data from disk, or it could be recomputing the tsvector in order to apply the ts_rank_cd to it.  Please turn on track_io_timing and run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` so we can see which.

Comment: "I did not found description about sort index in analyze".  EXPLAIN ANALYZE onlly shows the plan that was used, not the other plans not used.  Your possibly-ordering index wasn't used, so there is no info about it.  If you put a small LIMIT on this query, it might use the ordering index.  But it will not label it as such, you know it is being used for order by the absence of Sort nodes.

Comment: how to turn on `track_io_timing` for current session ? SET `track_io_timing = 1` ?

Comment: now it's `select name, setting, unit, source from pg_settings where name = 'track_io_timing';` => `track_io_timing off  default`. Jost to set `on` or `1` or `true`?

Comment: Yes, `set track_io_timing=on;`, but you need to be a superuser to do that.  If you are not a superuser, you could ask the dba to change the setting globally; the downside of turning it on is minimal in my experience.